# Javascript bind submit event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to bind an submit event to a button that can't be `type="submit"` needs to be `type="button"`
I'm trying these to make the `required` attr validation works

So, can you say what I'm doing wrong here? I'm Googling a lot but didn't find anything yet.

https://jsfiddle.net/2gfnqv6e/28/

Answer (score 2):

With this code, you can trigger the submit event :

```
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  form.dispatchEvent(submitEvent);
});
```

However the HTML5 form validation won't work because it requires an actual submit button.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gfnqv6e/29/)